# Trouble using PostgreSQL array from subquery as ANY expression

Tags: arrays, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to search in a table for values contained in an array. As an example, this query, using no subquery works as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM twitter_users 
WHERE twitter_id = ANY('{278929455,234874457,441723533,126840137}'::varchar[]);
```

But, when using a subquery in the any, it fails:

```
SELECT * 
FROM twitter_users 
WHERE twitter_id = ANY(
  SELECT follower_ids
  FROM twitter_followers_logs WHERE ID =
    (
      SELECT MAX(id) MaxId
      FROM twitter_followers_logs
      WHERE twitter_user_id = 2992
    )
);

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
LINE 3: WHERE twitter_id = ANY(
                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The tables are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE twitter_users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    twitter_id character varying,
    screen_name character varying
);

CREATE TABLE twitter_followers_logs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    twitter_user_id integer,
    follower_ids character varying[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[],
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

How can I get that subquery in a state to run the ANY expression correctly?

Comment: Your subquery doesn't return an array. The table "twitter_followers_logs" doesn't contain the column "Id" or the column "twitter_user_id". Paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for the *actual* tables into your question.

Comment: Thanks for reading, I added the create tables to clear up the confusion. I think I've got it now with a conversion on the subquery results. Doing some final tests.

Comment: You can write up your own results as an answer, and accept it.